# Classical mechanics; gravitation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, escape-velocity

> *There is a crater of depth $R/100$ on the surface of the moon (radius $R$). A projectile is fired vertically upward from the crater with a velocity, which is equal to the escape velocity from the surface of the moon. Find the maximum height attained by the projectile.*

The answer is $99.5 R$, but when I do it, I get $98R$. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Potential energy At crater + Kinetic energy at crater = Potential energy at highest point reached.

Potential energy at a point is $-GMm/R$.

$$ 0.5*mGM/R - GMm*100/99R = -GMm/(R+h).$$
Where $h$ is the height reached. Solving for $h$, I get $98R$.

Comment: Could you explain your kinetic energy term? One would expect it to be equal to the negative of the potential energy of the object at the surface...

Answer (score 1):

As Andres Salas said, your kinetic energy should be the negative of the potential energy at the surface. Also, you're using the wrong formula for the potential energy in the crater. $-GMm/r$ is correct only when $r\ge R$.

Comment: Yes. New mass considered whould be yet smaller with the distance tunneled in. Thanks (although I'm not OP). I thought the truth of that would be ignored due to the basic nature of the class the OP is taking. I'll try and confirm if this yields the 99.5 R we need

Comment: Also, let us not forget we mean height from crater, not height from surface m8.